# How to return NULL if xsi:nil = true (XML)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing

I have a problem when parsing a XML file. I would like to return NULL in my SQL table when `xsi:nil = true`. This is an example of the XML file:

```
<row>
  <data>blablabla</data>
</row>
<row>
  <date xsi:nil="true" />
</row>
```

Some of the `date` are empty, and should return `NULL` in my PHP foreach loop. Yet I think they return `" "` since the data cannot be read by my SQL loop.

This is an example of my PHP code:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//row') as $row) {
  $date= $row->xpath('./date');
  $item['date'] = $date[0];
  echo $item['date'].'<br/>';

 // insert the result in my SQL database //
 $sql = $sq_connexion->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (date) VALUES (:date)");
 $sql->execute(array('date' => $item['date']));

}
```

I would like to have, in my SQL database, the value `blablabla` for the first `date` and the value `NULL` when `xsi:nil="true"` is displayed. For the moment, with this kind of code, I have this error message:

```
 PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column 'date' at row 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with testing the attribute is that you need to fetch the attributes for a specific namespace.  So the test for having that attribute looks slightly different.  I've added some test data, but not able to test it with the database bit, so hope this works though...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$data = "<set xmlns:xsi='http://someurl.com'>
<row>
  <date>0000-00-00</date>
</row>
<row>
  <date xsi:nil=\"true\" />
</row>
</set>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//row') as $row) {
    $date = $row->date;
    if ( isset( $date->attributes('xsi', true)->nil ))   {
        $date = null;
    }

    // insert the result in my SQL database //
    $sql = $sq_connexion->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (date) VALUES (:date)");
    $sql->execute(array('date' => $date));
}
```